# SSRS filtering a Tablix column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a tablix like below

[image]

I have dropdown for years which is captured by a parameter @FY
When FY 2019 is selected, I want to replace Ian with Tom's Sales data in the above Tablix and for other years like 2017 and 2018 I want the Tablix to look the same as shown above. Can this be possible using expressions ?

Comment: Could you provide some data from your table?

Comment: where is `Tom's ` row data? Is the data contained in the table? What's the condition let `@FY = 2019` to select `Tom's `  data?

Comment: Tom's data is in the dataset that feeds this tablix. Yes only for FY2019 I want Tom's sales data to show up in the tablix else status quo.

Comment: I edit my answer you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE 
(name in ('Adam','Tom','James') AND (@FY = 2019))
OR
(name in ('Adam','lan','James') AND (@FY = 2018))
```

Comment: I tried similar approach but I'm aiming to integrate our logic into the SELECT statement that is fetching Sales agents already. Like i'm trying to implement the logic on the column 'Sales agent' of the SELECT statement.

Comment: It worked in some datasets but forming crossjoins in some datasets